# What's the best way to get the end of a wheel event in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to set an event when my wheel event is over.

I already saw a solution with a scroll event (which is quite similar) using a `setTimeout` function here : https://gomakethings.com/detecting-when-a-visitor-has-stopped-scrolling-with-vanilla-javascript/

But I wonder if there's a cleaner way to know when my wheel event stops returning something.

This is my wheel event so far :

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
   console.log(e.deltaY);
});
```

Comment: No. Debouncing and checking whether the user has not done scrolling after some timeout is the only way to detect this. There is no *single* "wheel event", there are multiple ones, and you want do define the "end" of a continuous streak.

Comment: Your question is basically asking "I wonder if there's a cleaner way to predict the future"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts is there ?

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @Bergi's answer, here's the code that detects the end of wheel usage:

```
let wheelEventEndTimeout = null;
window.addEventListener('wheel', () => {
    console.log('wheel is being used');
    clearTimeout(wheelEventEndTimeout);
    wheelEventEndTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('wheel end');
    }, 100);
});
```